# Unable to adjust partition of USB drive with Mountain Lion Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, usb, disk-utility, partition

I have a 500 GB USB drive, which I once partitioned into two parts: one encrypted—Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted), and the other not—Mac OS Extended (Journaled).

Now I want to change the partition layout, and probably add a new partition. However, I was unable to do this in Disk Utility: all options related to partitions are greyed out. See the screen cap for example (clicking on the partitions does not work, either).
[image: screen cap of disk utility]
This is pretty weird: not only can't I resize or add partition, I can't make any change to the partition layout, including completely reformatting the disk! Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot resize a drive that has been encrypted. You will first need to unencrypt the drive, then resize the partitions, then re-encrypt the drive.

Comment: That is a USB drive, not the Macintosh HD...

Comment: Removed the word FileVault. OS X will not allow an encrypted volume to resized. You may have luck with the command-line diskutil command if you are careful, but it's easier to unencrypt.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that USB drives are also encrypted with FileVault. This is lame, though. I ended up erasing all the contents to update partition. One thing I don't understand: why don't they allow resizing unencrypted partitions? (Well regarding memory and storage I know nothing beyond virtual memory, so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.)

Comment: If all volumes on a physical drive are unencrypted then you can resize the partitions, provided there is enough physical free space at the end of a volume (Disk Utility shows this as a blue bar within each volume in your screenshot). If a single partition is encrypted and you want to resize another partition, I don't believe Disk Utility will allow you. I am not sure the reasoning, it may have to do with integrity of the encryption and how OS X validates it. That, however, is a guess.