# Unable to extend my partition

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition

I have searched through this site alot and i wasn't able to find any solutions.

My situation is the following:
I decided to install linux to dual boot with OSX at my 1TB fully encrypted with FV2 hard drive.
I opened the disk utility and i shrinked the main partition to 500GB. I created another one with 500GB to install linux there.
Right after i did that, i changed my mind :S and wanted to expand the OSX partition again to be 1TB.
This is what I get - everything is greyed out and I'm not able to do anything:
[image]
[image]

I 've tried to reboot and boot with cmd+r to enter the system recovery and run disk utility from there - the results are the same. I 'm desperate:/

Comment: I have FV2 switched on. I don't know what and how to resize with the cmdline "diskutil corestorage". Could have you got any more specific advice?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that i did it using this post [Unable to Resize Partitions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134498/unable-to-resize-partitions) and your comment.

Although it wasn't obvious for me, what I did was this:

```
diskutil corestorage resizeStack LOGICAL_VOLUME_UUID 0G
```

0G to expand it to the maximum available space that is free.

```
diskutil corestorage resizeStack
```

can provide with info.

Comment: I cannot find how to mark it as solved :/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was using `resizeStack` unsuccessfully because I couldn't find the exact right size to put in and it was creating an invalid volume. I didn't know 0G would just take up all available free space!