# The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition. Windows 10 and Sierra

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

Getting is error trying to remove my Win 10 Partition.

"disktutil list" shows the following. Any ideas?

```
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Mac OS                  29.4 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Mac OS                 +29.0 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 B7D96129-BE28-48C5-98EB-39FAF8A90FD1
                                 Unencrypted
```

Comment: Ouch. 29 GB for macOS. You’re being sorely punished. Why not boot to recovery and erase install? There can’t be much data you need to recover from that - but we’re left to guess since you didn’t ask for something specific in your good setup for a question.

Comment: The stock answer to this question (which has been asked more times than I can remember) would be to enter the command `sudo diskutil cs resizestack B7D96129-BE28-48C5-98EB-39FAF8A90FD1 0` in a Terminal application window. Post a comment if this command fixes the problem or not.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - could you figure out which of these could be canonical we can flag the others as dupes against? Maybe raise it in meta?

Comment: @Tetsujin: If you seach [resizestack](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Newest&q=resizestack), then the [oldest link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134498/unable-to-resize-partitions/134531#134531) mentions `resizestack`. The [next oldest link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148522/unable-to-extend-my-partition/148528#148528) mentions using `0` for the size. This predates any Core Storage answers posted by [klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) or me.