# How do I resize an ex-CoreStorage volume?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

I've got a Macbook Pro Retina (with the PCIe drive ‘blade’, instead of a traditional 2.5" laptop drive). I've recently upgraded the internal drive from 500GB to 1TB, and `dd`'d the old drive over the new one to retain my partition setup and Bootcamp partition.

Unfortunately, this didn't go well: for whatever reason, OS X wouldn't recognize, once I'd booted up on the new 1TB drive, that there was 500GB of new space available. It was showing up in Disk Utility as greyed-out space.

To aid in debugging this, I wiped out the Bootcamp partition entirely (I have backups. I intend to restore that later, once I've got the drive fixed up from within OS X.); and eventually, after getting fed up trying to get `diskutil cs resizeStack` to work, I `diskutil cs revert`'ed the boot volume entirely.

---

Now I have this situation:

```
> diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Fannie's HD             499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
> diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
> diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 limits
For device disk0s2 Fannie's HD:
        Current size:  499.4 GB (499418034176 Bytes)
        Minimum size:  330.0 GB (329959456768 Bytes)
        Maximum size:  499.4 GB (499418034176 Bytes)
```

[image]

After trying to drag the single partition in Disk Utility from 500GB up to 1TB, and then clicking ‘apply’, the process appears to proceed, and complete; but as soon as the completion message appears in the bottom-right, the partition map reverts to what you see in the screenshot. It never succeeds in re-sizing to 1TB. (Here's the [verbose log](https://gist.github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/feb53a127e1cc77d7b8a), along with some other details obtained from the command-line.)

(Attempting to do the same from the recovery partition's Disk Utility gives an ‘Error: could not unmount disk.)

At this point, all I want in the world, is to re-size the single partition on my drive from 500GB to fill the available 1TB of space. Once I succeed with this, I'll be able to convert it to a CoreStorage volume, encrypt it, partition for Bootcamp and such.

Please help!

***Edit:*** Other posts I've read through: [Christian's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume), and [Chrisii's summary of undocumented CoreStorage commands](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/134531/15184)

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` to the question.

Comment: Ammended [the gist linked above](https://gist.github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/feb53a127e1cc77d7b8a)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you

1. **backup** your data before you running the command below
2. Repair disk via Disk Utility App in Recovery Mode if needed

and then run this command in terminal

`diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 0b`

Comment: This worked! I have no idea why, after all the things I tried, but it worked! Thank you so much, guys.