# Can't create a partition

Tags: macos, partition

I'm trying to create a new partition for installing linux, but OSX won't let me.

I saw this question: [Unable to Resize Partitions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134498/unable-to-resize-partitions), but my HD is not a CoreStorage Volume, so it didn't really help. 
[image]

checking for corestorage in the terminal:

```
$diskutil cs list    
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Edit: extra info - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Fj9KvcRx

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize you have posted your own answer, but others may want to know what was wrong.

Basically, you had journaling turned off. To turn journaling on, you need to highlight the partition and click on the "Enable Journaling" button. To see the change, you may have to quit and reopen the Disk Utility application.

To turn journaling off, do the following using the Disk Utility application.

1. Highlight the partition.
2. Press and hold the "alt/option" key.
3. From the menu bar select "File->Disable Journaling"
4. Release the "alt/option" key.
5. Quit and reopen the Disk Utility

You should alway have journaling enabled for "Mac OS Extended" formatted partitions, but there can be cases where you may want to turn it off. Especially if you are going to be using Linux.  Many linux distributions (like Ubuntu) can read "Mac OS Extended" formatted partitions, but they can only write to them if journaling is turn off. So enabling and disabling journaling may be useful if you need to transfer data from Linux to OS X.

Comment: Ah, that's why. I had disabled journaling previously for exactly that reason (wanted linux to be able to write to the mac partition). Turning journaling on and off does indeed affect your ability to resize the partition from inside disk utility.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really wise to try repartition the disk you're booted from, so Disk Utility doesn't let you.

You can boot from a [USB key containing a recovery partition](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372) or a CD/DVD if your Mac is old enough to have a Superdrive.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm trying to install Linux, I just booted from the Linux usb that I made, logged in with the "test linux" mode, then partitioned the disk using `gpart`.